# Subsetting array of dates according to recessions in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I would like to subset an array of serial numbers representing dates, according to recession periods, so that I can calculate `mean()` over these periods. The following example illustrate this:

```
DateArray = transpose((1:20000)+678420);
RndData = normrnd(0.003,0.05,19999,1);
CumData = cumprod([1;RndData+1]);

Data = [DateArray CumData];

load Data_Recessions.mat %Native `Econometrics toolbox` dataset
% This loads a 2 column double array of start dates in the first column and corresponding end dates in the second column.


plot(Data(:,1),Data(:,2))
set(gca(),'Yscale','log');
recessionplot()
```

[image]

I thus want to calculate mean() over the grey bars above. The dates indicating these periods are in the Recessions array. How do I do this most efficiently?

Comment: What do you get from `load Data_Recessions.mat`? Specifically in what form / shape / size are your data?

Comment: It is a Econometrics Toolbox dataset. It loads the variable Recessions. It is a two column double array with the recession start dates in the first column and the corresponding end dates in the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your recession dates are in a 2 column matrix called D

```
M = arrayfun(@(x)(mean(Data(find(Data(:,1)==D(x,1)):find(Data(:,1)==D(x,2)),2))), 1:size(D,1))
```

Or as a for loop which is actually probably more efficient:

```
M = NaN(size(D,1),1);
for x = 1:size(D,1)
    first = find(Data(:,1)==D(x,1))
    last = find(Data(:,1)==D(x,2))
    M(x) = mean(Data(first:last, 2))
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Had hoped that a task so simple (at least in my mind) would be much more simple. I miss ´R´ :)

Comment: @Mace More simple?? It's just a couple lines... but there may very well be a function that does just this in your econometrics toolbox, but I don't have it I'm afraid. Also check out the file exchange...

Comment: I'm just used to R, where I would be able to do it in one short and simple line.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the average in grey as well as white periods. It builds an index to be used as label for each data value, and then applies [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to average all values with the same label:

```
ind = sum(bsxfun(@ge, Data(:,1).', [0; reshape(Date_Recessions.',[],1)]),1)
result = accumarray(ind(:), Data(:,2), [], @mean);
```